# Create while loop function that takes next largest value untill condition is met

Tags: r, function, loops, intervals

I want to create a function that creates a new column in a dataframe that starts with all 0's in all rows but will create 1's based on the following. It starts looking at the highest % in the percent column. That will produce a 1 in the newly created "algorithm" column in the same row. Then it will look at the minimum and maximum row of the starting row. Lets say the highest found (starting value) is 13,8% in row 6, the next rows that it will look at are 5 and 7. Then it will look at the percentages in here and decides the highest % and creates a 1 in the "algorithm" column ( lets say it is 8,3% in row 7). Next it will look at the min and max row again ( row 5 and row 8, because row 6&7 are already took into account).

Then an important factor as well is that it has to stop at a certain percentage with looking for more rows, lets say at 95% it is stopping. This is based on the total percentage from the "percent" column that summed up should be 95% .

This is the main idea, but Im not sure how to do this.

Moreover, it also in the end has to look further than the min and max row since those 2 rows can also be both for example be 8%, so it has to look 1 row further and choose that row based on the highest value.

Not tested yet, but this is what im thinking about currently.

```
(While(total_perc < p_min_performance)  
prev_row_value <t (minrow -1)
next_rpw_value <t (maxrow +1)

prev > next > t(prev,)  >1
minrow <- minrow-1
maxrow <- maxrow+1
```

Sample code:

```
algorithm <- data.frame(pc4 = c(5464),
timeinterval = c('08:45:00', '09:00:00', '09:15:00', '09:30:00', 
'09:45:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '10:30:00', '10:45:00', '11:00:00', 
'11:15:00', '11:30:00'),
stops = c(1, 5, 8, 7, 5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8)) %>%
mutate(percent = round(stops/sum(stops), digits = 6)*100) %>%
mutate(idgroup = seq_along(timeinterval))
```

Not sure where to start yet. EDIT: THe 1's in the algorithm_clumn can also be the corresponding percentages, which maybe makes it easier to count it up until lets say 95%.

The structure should look like this (its an example, the data in the algorithm_column could be anything based on what it is finding in the data)

```
EDIT:
algorithm
#    pc4 timeinterval stops percent idgroup algorithm_column
#1  5464     08:45:00     1  1.3889       1                0
#2  5464     09:00:00     5  6.9444       2                1
#3  5464     09:15:00     8 11.1111       3                1
#4  5464     09:30:00     7  9.7222       4                1
#5  5464     09:45:00     5  6.9444       5                1
#6  5464     10:00:00    10 13.8889       6                1
#7  5464     10:15:00     6  8.3333       7                1
#8  5464     10:30:00     4  5.5556       8                1
#9  5464     10:45:00     7  9.7222       9                1
#10 5464     11:00:00     6  8.3333      10                1
#11 5464     11:15:00     5  6.9444      11                1
#12 5464     11:30:00     8 11.1111      12                0
```

The code of Ronak is working:

```
algorithm$algorithm_column <- 0

output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(algorithm, algorithm$pc4), 
function(x) {
     all_index <- x$idgroup
     next_comb <- all_index
     while(sum(x$percent[x$algorithm_column == 1]) <= 95) {
        inds <- next_comb[which.max(x$percent[next_comb])]
        x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
        nos <- which(all_index == inds)
         next_comb <- all_index[c(nos - 1, nos + 1)]
        all_index <- setdiff(all_index, inds)
     }
    x
}))
```

EDIT: The function is not working in some cases because when it reaches two 0's in the next rows it will take the FIRST max of those rows and it will find only 0's in the first part of the data set and then continues to the next highest value. For example, this dataset:

```
algorithm1 <- data.frame(pc4 = c(8035),
timeinterval = c('03:00:00','03:30:00','04:00:00','04:30:00','05:00:00','05:30:00','06:00:00','06:30:00','07:00:00','07:30:00','08:00:00','08:30:00','09:00:00','09:30:00','10:00:00','10:30:00','11:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00','12:30:00','13:00:00','13:30:00','14:00:00','14:30:00','15:00:00','15:30:00','16:00:00','16:30:00'),
stops =  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 70, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0))  %>%
group_by(pc4) %>%
mutate(percent = round(stops/sum(stops), digits = 6)*100) %>%
mutate(idgroup = seq_along(timeinterval)) %>%
mutate(algorithm_column = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I added the iteration to the function to see the order, so you can see that it takes the 0's first.

```
p_min_performance <- 95         # SET PERCENTAGE!
#Naar 0
algorithm1$algorithm_column <- 0
algorithm1$iteration <- 0
it <- 0
algorithm1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(algorithm1, algorithm1$pc4), 
function(x) {
#Index voor maximum percentage
all_index <- x$idgroup
next_comb <- all_index
#While loop algorithm
while (sum(x$percent[x$algorithm_column == 1]) <= p_min_performance) {
it <- it + 1
inds <- next_comb[which.max(x$percent[next_comb])]
x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
x$iteration[inds] <- it
nos <- which(all_index == inds)
next_comb <- all_index[c(nos - 1, nos + 1)]
all_index <- setdiff(all_index, inds)
}
x
}))
```

Output how it is now: (where timeinterval will be from 03:00 to 15:00)

```
   pc4   tinterval  stops   percen id_g a_col iteration
1   8035    03:00:00    0   0.0000  1   1   14
2   8035    03:30:00    0   0.0000  2   1   13
3   8035    04:00:00    0   0.0000  3   1   12
4   8035    04:30:00    0   0.0000  4   1   11
5   8035    05:00:00    0   0.0000  5   1   10
6   8035    05:30:00    0   0.0000  6   1   9
7   8035    06:00:00    0   0.0000  7   1   8
8   8035    06:30:00    0   0.0000  8   1   7
9   8035    07:00:00    0   0.0000  9   1   6
10  8035    07:30:00    0   0.0000  10  1   5
11  8035    08:00:00    0   0.0000  11  1   4
12  8035    08:30:00    0   0.0000  12  1   3
13  8035    09:00:00    9   9.0909  13  1   2
14  8035    09:30:00    70  70.7071 14  1   1
15  8035    10:00:00    0   0.0000  15  1   15
16  8035    10:30:00    6   6.0606  16  1   16
17  8035    11:00:00    0   0.0000  17  1   17
18  8035    11:30:00    0   0.0000  18  1   18
19  8035    12:00:00    0   0.0000  19  1   19
20  8035    12:30:00    3   3.0303  20  1   20
21  8035    13:00:00    0   0.0000  21  1   21
22  8035    13:30:00    3   3.0303  22  1   22
23  8035    14:00:00    3   3.0303  23  1   23
24  8035    14:30:00    0   0.0000  24  1   24
25  8035    15:00:00    5   5.0505  25  1   25
26  8035    15:30:00    0   0.0000  26  0   0
27  8035    16:00:00    0   0.0000  27  0   0
28  8035    16:30:00    0   0.0000  28  0   0
```

But this should be: (where timeinterval will be from 09:00 to 15:00)

```
   pc4   tinterval  stops   percen id_g a_col iteration
1   8035    03:00:00    0   0.0000  1   0   0
2   8035    03:30:00    0   0.0000  2   0   0
3   8035    04:00:00    0   0.0000  3   0   0
4   8035    04:30:00    0   0.0000  4   0   0
5   8035    05:00:00    0   0.0000  5   0   0
6   8035    05:30:00    0   0.0000  6   0   0
7   8035    06:00:00    0   0.0000  7   0   0
8   8035    06:30:00    0   0.0000  8   0   0
9   8035    07:00:00    0   0.0000  9   0   0
10  8035    07:30:00    0   0.0000  10  0   0
11  8035    08:00:00    0   0.0000  11  0   0
12  8035    08:30:00    0   0.0000  12  0   0
13  8035    09:00:00    9   9.0909  13  1   2
14  8035    09:30:00    70  70.7071 14  1   1
15  8035    10:00:00    0   0.0000  15  1   3
16  8035    10:30:00    6   6.0606  16  1   4
17  8035    11:00:00    0   0.0000  17  1   5
18  8035    11:30:00    0   0.0000  18  1   6
19  8035    12:00:00    0   0.0000  19  1   7
20  8035    12:30:00    3   3.0303  20  1   8
21  8035    13:00:00    0   0.0000  21  1   9
22  8035    13:30:00    3   3.0303  22  1   10
23  8035    14:00:00    3   3.0303  23  1   11
24  8035    14:30:00    0   0.0000  24  1   12
25  8035    15:00:00    5   5.0505  25  1   13
26  8035    15:30:00    0   0.0000  26  0   0
27  8035    16:00:00    0   0.0000  27  0   0
28  8035    16:30:00    0   0.0000  28  0   0
```

So the algorithm in the end should look at the rows further then only the row next to the highest value if these are both 0.

I was now busy with creating chunks of it but im a but stuck..

```
runAlgorithm <- function(x, min_performance = 95) {
x$algorithm_column <- 0
x$iteration <- 0

it <- 0

all_index <- x$idgroup
next_comb <- all_index

inds <- next_comb[which.max(x$percent[next_comb])]
x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
 x$iteration[inds] <- it

#While loop algorithm
while (sum(x$percent[x$algorithm_column == 1]) <= min_performance) {

prev_values <- x$percent[1:inds - 1]
next_values <- x$percent[inds + 1:length(x$percent)]
first_non_zero_prev <- if_else(sum(prev_values) > 0L, which.max(prev_values 
> 0), NA)
first_non_zero_next <- if_else(sum(next_values) > 0L, which.max(next_values 
> 0), NA)
next_value <- case_when(
  is.na(first_non_zero_prev) & !is.na(first_non_zero_next) ~ next_comb[2],
  !is.na(first_non_zero_prev) & is.na(first_non_zero_next) ~ next_comb[1],
  first_non_zero_prev <= first_non_zero_next ~ next_comb[2],
  first_non_zero_prev > first_non_zero_next ~ next_comb[1]
)

inds <- next_comb[which.max(x$percent[next_value])]
x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
x$iteration[inds] <- it

nos <- which(all_index == inds)
next_comb <- all_index[c(nos - 1, nos + 1)]
all_index <- setdiff(all_index, inds)
}
return(x)
}
df_test <- groep_test[1:48,]
output <- runAlgorithm(df_test)
```

Comment: Please see the picture

Comment: The picture does not seem to match the description. "Then it will look at the percentages in here and decides the highest % and creates a 1 in the "algorithm" column ( lets say it is 8,3% in row 7)". That implies that row 5 would have 0 but in your picture it is 0. Also, instead of a picture, you should provide the information in your post.

Comment: The picture is what I want to see in end, so its at something near 75% in total in the picture (should be 95% or so in the end). It is indeed not corresponding with the text i wrote, because that is how the process goes.

Comment: How can folks help if your description doesn't match? Right now, if the picture is the only thing we can follow, the answer would be ```c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)```. To have some semblance of matching, your picture should have rows 5 and 8 as 0 because they are both below your minimum threshold.

Comment: The description is right, the picture is just an example of how it would look like in the end, not how it should look like with the 1's at those places. In the end is should be a chain of 1's, there can not be a zero in between. Because i want to end up having a time interval from [a random time] untill [ a random time]. The picture as example would have a time interval from 09:15 untill 11:00 with 63,58% of the observations in it (summing up 1,11%, 9,72%, 6,94% untill 8,33%, which are the 1's in the other column)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
#Remaining index
all_index <- algorithm$idgroup
#Initialising to 0
algorithm$algorithm_column <- 0
#Index to check for maximum
next_comb <- all_index
#While more than 20% of the rows are remaining.
#Change this to whatever number you wish. For 95% use 0.05 
while(sum(x$percent[x$algorithm_column == 1]) <= 95) {
   #Get maximum index
   inds <- next_comb[which.max(algorithm$percent[next_comb])]
   #Change the value to 1
   algorithm$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
   nos <- which(all_index == inds)
   #Get the next two indices
   next_comb <- all_index[c(nos - 1, nos + 1)]
   #Remove the previously used index.
   all_index <- setdiff(all_index, inds)
}
```

Since we have limited number of rows, this stops after filling 10 rows out of 12.

```
algorithm
#    pc4 timeinterval stops percent idgroup algorithm_column
#1  5464     08:45:00     1  1.3889       1                0
#2  5464     09:00:00     5  6.9444       2                1
#3  5464     09:15:00     8 11.1111       3                1
#4  5464     09:30:00     7  9.7222       4                1
#5  5464     09:45:00     5  6.9444       5                1
#6  5464     10:00:00    10 13.8889       6                1
#7  5464     10:15:00     6  8.3333       7                1
#8  5464     10:30:00     4  5.5556       8                1
#9  5464     10:45:00     7  9.7222       9                1
#10 5464     11:00:00     6  8.3333      10                1
#11 5464     11:15:00     5  6.9444      11                1
#12 5464     11:30:00     8 11.1111      12                0
```

---

For multiple groups, we can `split` the data based on `pc4` and apply the same for each group.

```
algorithm$algorithm_column <- 0

 output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(algorithm, algorithm$pc4), function(x) {
     all_index <- x$idgroup
     next_comb <- all_index
     while(sum(x$percent[x$algorithm_column == 1]) <= 95) {
        inds <- next_comb[which.max(x$percent[next_comb])]
        x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1
        nos <- which(all_index == inds)
        next_comb <- all_index[c(nos - 1, nos + 1)]
        all_index <- setdiff(all_index, inds)
    }
    x
}))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks like its working. Although, if i'm setting the threshold on 0.05 for 95% accuracy it is still taking row 1, while it is already on 1.3889% - 100 = 98,6111% accuracy (combining the rest of the rows and looking at what percentage they have in the "percent column". Do you know why?

Comment: @SaschaS What does threshold mean here ? I am just taking ratio of number of rows which are 1. Maybe you need to add `sum(algorithm$percent[algorithm$algorithm_column == 1]) <= 95` in the `while` loop condition.

Comment: Thanks that worked! However, if I have a dataset that is totally the same but has different pc4's (idgroup will still count from 1 untill 12 for every pc4) how would I do this? So basically on row 13 this all starts over again but with different data, grouped on lets say pc4 with 5465.

Comment: @SaschaS I have updated the answer which will work for multiple groups. Can you check?

Comment: The loop works, but in a pc4 group I set the minimum at 95, the algorithm found rows until 2 rows with 0% and 0% (bottom, top), when there is still a row with 8.5% (1 below a row with 0%) In this case it takes both the 0% rows (not minimum of 95 reached), takes the next 8,5% at the bottom and then all the 0% rows on top. This makes my time interval go from not 10:00 to 16:00 but 00:00 to 16:00. maybe code should look not at only next 2 rows, but if those next two rows are the same -> it looks at the rows next to those and picks the highest one. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @ Ronak shah could you help me? :)

Comment: @SaschaS It is not clear to me what you are asking. Can you share an example where the current code fails and behaves incorrectly and also show the correct behaviour (expected output) ?

Comment: @SaschaS do you want to turn all the 0 values in `percent` to 0 or only the starting ones ? If all the values add `x$algorithm_column[x$percent[inds] == 0] <- 0` Or if only the starting one add `x$algorithm_column[cumsum(x$percent[inds]) <= 0] <- 0` after this line `x$algorithm_column[inds] <- 1` in `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that is not based on a loop. Basically, it uses the `cumsum()` to determine which rows cross the `maximum_threshold`. The `rowSums(matrix(...))` combines rows 5 and 7, then 4 and 8, etc. from your example.

Based on your comments you could add this to a `dplyr` chain, including with `group_by()`.

```
f_algo_return <- function(pct, max_threshold = 70){
  # initialize return variable
  algo <- vector(mode = 'integer', length = length(pct))

  #make rows
  max_row <- which.max(pct)

  #if we have odd number of rows, we need to prevent subsetting pct[0]
  len_out <- min(abs(max_row - c(1, length(pct))))

  all_rows <- c(max_row,
                (max_row - len_out):(max_row-1),
                (max_row+1):(max_row + len_out)
  )

  #subset the pct
  pct <- pct[all_rows]

  thresh <- cumsum(c(pct[1], rowSums(matrix(pct[-1], ncol = 2)))) < max_threshold
  sub_rows <- all_rows[c(thresh[1], rev(thresh[-1]), thresh[-1])]

  #initialize and update new variable
  algo[sub_rows] <- 1L

  return(algo)
}

f_algo_return(DF[['percent']])
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

data:

```
DF <- data.frame(pc4 = c(5464),
                        timeinterval = c('08:45:00', '09:00:00', '09:15:00', '09:30:00', 
                                         '09:45:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '10:30:00', '10:45:00', '11:00:00', 
                                         '11:15:00', '11:30:00'),
                        stops = c(1, 5, 8, 7, 5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8)) %>%
  mutate(percent = round(stops/sum(stops), digits = 6)*100) %>%
  mutate(idgroup = seq_along(timeinterval))
```