# Min and max value based on another column and combine those in r

Tags: r, max, conditional-statements, min

So I basically got a while loop function that creates 1's in the "algorithm_column" based on the highest percentages in the "percent" column, until a certain total percentage is reached (90% or something). The rest of the rows that are not taken into account will have a value of 0 in the "algorithm_column" ( [Create while loop function that takes next largest value untill condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817324/create-while-loop-function-that-takes-next-largest-value-untill-condition-is-met))

I want to show, based on what the loop function found, the min and max times of the column "timeinterval" (the min is where the 1's start and max is the last row with a 1, the 0's are out of the scope). And then finally create a time interval from this.

So if we have the following code, I want to create in another column, lets say "total_time" a calculation from the min time 09:00 ( this is where 1 start in the algorithm_column) until 11:15, which makes a time interval of 02:15 hours added to the "total_time" column.

```
algorithm
#    pc4 timeinterval stops percent idgroup algorithm_column
#1  5464     08:45:00     1  1.3889       1                0
#2  5464     09:00:00     5  6.9444       2                1
#3  5464     09:15:00     8 11.1111       3                1
#4  5464     09:30:00     7  9.7222       4                1
#5  5464     09:45:00     5  6.9444       5                1
#6  5464     10:00:00    10 13.8889       6                1
#7  5464     10:15:00     6  8.3333       7                1
#8  5464     10:30:00     4  5.5556       8                1
#9  5464     10:45:00     7  9.7222       9                1
#10 5464     11:00:00     6  8.3333      10                1
#11 5464     11:15:00     5  6.9444      11                1
#12 5464     11:30:00     8 11.1111      12                0
```

I have multiple pc4 groups, so it should look at every group and calculate a total_time for each group respectively.

I got this function, but I'm a bit stuck if this is what I need.

```
test <- function(x) {
  ind <- x[["algorithm$algorithm_column"]] == 0
  Mx <- max(x[["timeinterval"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE);
  ind <- x[["algorithm$algorithm_column"]] == 1
  Mn <- min(x[["timeinterval"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE);
  list(Mn, Mx)  ## or return(list(Mn, Mx))
}

test(algorithm)
```

Comment: I don't understand your data structure: you pass a list as `x` and the data.frame`algorithm` is one of the list's members?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

algorithm %>%
  mutate(tmp = cumsum(c(0, diff(algorithm_column) != 0))) %>%
  filter(algorithm_column == 1) %>%
  group_by(pc4, tmp) %>%
  summarise(first = first(timeinterval),
            last = last(timeinterval)) %>%
  select(-tmp)
## A tibble: 1 x 3
## Groups:   pc4 [1]
#    pc4 first    last    
#  <int> <fct>    <fct>   
#1  5464 09:00:00 11:15:00
```

**Data.**

```
algorithm <- read.table(text = "
    pc4 timeinterval stops percent idgroup algorithm_column
1  5464     08:45:00     1  1.3889       1                0
2  5464     09:00:00     5  6.9444       2                1
3  5464     09:15:00     8 11.1111       3                1
4  5464     09:30:00     7  9.7222       4                1
5  5464     09:45:00     5  6.9444       5                1
6  5464     10:00:00    10 13.8889       6                1
7  5464     10:15:00     6  8.3333       7                1
8  5464     10:30:00     4  5.5556       8                1
9  5464     10:45:00     7  9.7222       9                1
10 5464     11:00:00     6  8.3333      10                1
11 5464     11:15:00     5  6.9444      11                1
12 5464     11:30:00     8 11.1111      12                0
", header = TRUE)
```